# Calling actionscript2.0 method from javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript

How to call AS2 method from Javascript?

Without ExternalInterface use.

Comment: I'm curious - why would you not like to use externalInterface?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.actionScript2) {
    var AS2 = new window.actionScript2;
    // use AS2
}
```

Just wait for me to implement a browser that has the window.actionScript2 property.

Comment: If you want to call AS2 method you need to create a bridge between JS & flash. That's your externalinterface, you really have little choice. If you really don't want to do I assume you can hack together an IE only activeX control to do it aswell. But then you become evil for using activeX controls.

Comment: In other words, SWF is embed in html. I wanna call AS2 method in SWF with Javascript.